# Articles titles are not showing up in Uber template

Tags: articles

I installed Uber template, but the article titles in the Category are not showing. Please what do I do?

Comment: If you switch back to another template and the article titles ARE showing then open up the /templates/uber_template/html/content/category_item.php file and then edit your question and post all that file in there so we can look at it.

Answer (score -2):

Put `style="xhtml"` at `index.php` for uber template

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="???" style="xhtml" />
```

Comment: Changing the modChrome styling of a module has nothing to with Article titles.